# Match height of two HTML elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a sidebar that occasionally extends further than the main content ([as here](http://evangelicaltextualcriticism.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/new-book-pericope-of-adulteress-in.html?m=0)). I'd like to clip the sidebar's height when this happens by setting its max-height to match that of the main content. 
 
(**Note:** I'm using blogger, so fixing the HTML is more hassle than it's worth for this which is why I'd rather find a JS solution.)

The script I'm trying to get to work is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .text1 {border:1px solid red;}
    .text2 {border:1px solid blue;overflow:scroll;}
</style>
<body>

    <div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
    <div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. </div>

<script>
    function sidebar(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("text2").style.maxHeight = document.document.getElementsByClassName("text1").clientHeight;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead

*Note that your function needs to be executed as well, and I also changed your CSS to overflow: auto, so scroll bar only shows when needed*

```js
function sidebar(){
  document.querySelector(".text2").style.maxHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".text1"),null).getPropertyValue("height");
};
sidebar();    /*  added  */
```

```css
.text1 {border:1px solid red;}
.text2 {border:1px solid blue;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. </div>
<div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. </div>
```

*Note 2, you can also use [`closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to have your function execute*

```
(function sidebar(){
  document.querySelector(".text2").style.maxHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".text1"),null).getPropertyValue("height");
})();
```

So your code will finally end up looking something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style type="text/css">
    .text1 {border:1px solid red;}
    .text2 {border:1px solid blue;overflow:auto;}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. </div>
    <div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui. </div>

    <script>
    (function sidebar(){
      document.querySelector(".text2").style.maxHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".text1"),null).getPropertyValue("height");
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because in your code you are trying to read and write properties from any array (not from a DOM node). `document.getElementsByClassName()` function returns an array of DOM nodes. you can't read or write DOM specific properties on this array. You need to select a DOM node from this array with index notation. For example a first element can be selected as `document.getElementsByClassName('text1')[0]` etc etc.
And further you need to run your function too as shown below:

```js
(function sidebar(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("text2")[0].style.maxHeight =  document.getElementsByClassName("text1")[0].clientHeight + 'px';
})();
```

```css
.text1 {
  border:1px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
.text2 {
  border:1px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor... Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
<div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis massa sed mi viverra dapibus. Ut pulvinar a elit et sollicitudin. Aenean at augue dui.Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor...Lorem ipsum dolor... </div>
```

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) return a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array.

Comment: @LGSon yes, you are right. In fact, my intention was to write 'Array like object' but i worte 'array' instead :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 elements within a container of same height then the easiest way to do that is :-

```
.parent_container {
display: flex;
}
```

just add a div that will contain both these divs (.parent_container) and
Flexbox will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$(".text2").height($(".text1").height())`